# How am I able to get yesterday's Julian date in bash?

Tags: bash, date, julian-date

I am trying to save yesterday's Julian date in a script so I can call it again. However, when trying to test it in my terminal I am unable to get yesterdays Julian date, only yesterdays date.

The code that I have tried is:

```
date +%j -1 day
date +"%j -1 day"
date --%j="-1 days ago"
```

The output (for today's date) should be 266 and I am either returning an error:

```
date: unrecognized option '--%j=-1 days ago'
Try 'date --help' for more information.
```

Or 
    267 -1 day

Thank you!

Comment: First of all, you are asking the day of the year, not the [Julian Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day), that is something completely different. If you want to do add a day which is different then _now_, you should use the `-d` flag (see `man date`). The command you are after is `$ date -d "-1 days" "+%j"`

Answer (score 1):

You want `date +%j -d '1 day ago'`. It's the `-d` option that specifies what date you want to format (instead of `now`).